# Java while(condition doesn't reach)?? Why

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Why is it when I do this

```
while(word.charAt(left) == word.charAt(right) && left >= 0 && right < word.length()){
            left--;
            right++;
        }
```

its says in the while conditions "left >= 0 && right < word.length()" condition doesn't reach, but when I do it like this

```
 while(left >= 0 && right < word.length() && word.charAt(left) == word.charAt(right)){
            left--;
            right++;

        }
```

The conditions are met.
Is there an order for while(loop conditions)???

Comment: Because when you do it the other way around you access invalid indices and then check if they are valid. If you think about that, you may realize why it doesn't work.

Comment: The operators && and || are often called short-circuit operators because if the first operand is enough to prove the value, then it doesnt evaluate the second. For example, in ``a && b``, if a is false, then b is never evaluated.

Comment: Okay Thanks you for explaining!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order does matter as conditions are checked from left to right. You're getting that message because if the previous condition evaluates to true, then those two conditions

```
left >= 0 && right < word.length()
```

will always evaluate to true. You probably want the latter (since you would want to check all the conditions).

Comment: Sorry, but to evaluate to true, both parameters must be evaluated in an ``and`` operation. However, if the first condition evaluates to false, then the second condition isn't evaluated because ``false && ?`` evaluates to false.

Comment: That's true though what I meant is those two conditions will always evaluate to true if previous conditions are true. For example, if you want to check the first character of a string, you wouldn't have to check whether it's empty after you check the character. You would want to check if it's empty first and then check the character.